# Bulging capacitor - already leaked? replace urgently?

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor, glue

I spotted a bulging capacitor through the top vent of my stereo amplifier, with white goo around the base (at top of first picture). The amplifier seems to work fine, though it has been in storage for many years and probably a wide range of temperatures (sub freezing winter to 30+ degree C summers - not ideal, I know). I pulled the cover off to get a better look at the problem. It seems that the white goo might be glue applied to the base of the capacitor, from comparing to other large capacitors in the amplifier (second picture). I poked it, and it seems quite hard. The top of capacitor is definitely bulging, and I am worried that if it has not burst already it will soon.

My questions are:

- is the white goop indeed just glue?
- if it is glue: what is its purpose?
- does the capacitor need to be removed urgently?

[image: suspected leaking cap]
[image: good caps with glue]

Comment: White is old Polyurethane adhesive to prevent thru hole solder joint fatigue and annual ring insulation. (open circuit)  Looks like more than one cap has gas pressure bulge from excessive  RMS ripple current ^2*ESR product.

Comment: @Tony Stewart Which specific (additional) capacitor looks bulging to you? The large ones in the lower pic have flat tops, though they look a bit dome shaped, while the smaller ones in that pic are the same three as shown in the first pic.

Comment: Get an ESR meter, pull it off the board and check it. If it's bad then replace it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
is the white goop indeed just glue?
```

Yes

```
if it is glue: what is its purpose?
```

To stop the capacitor from wobbling and breaking its leads off.

```
does the capacitor need to be removed urgently?
```

No, but it probably has reduced performance and will fail soon, so replacing it would be a good idea.